# Target first `li` having specific class inside `ul` with css only

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to target first `li` having specific class inside `ul`? for example :

```
 <ul>
     <li class="a"></li> <!-- I want to target this li -->
     <li class="a"></li>
     <li class="a"></li>
     <li class="b"></li> <!-- and this li -->
     <li class="b"></li>
     <li class="b"></li>
 </ul>
```

Any possibility?

Comment: what is your definition of `specific` class ? Because they are not unique. Also, are you looking to target any "change" in class names ?

Comment: [Helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class)

Comment: I would say add ids to the html but then again, I don't know if changing the html is even possible in your case.

Comment: @karthikr sorry if that specific word is misleading. I dont know the excat no of li's but i want to target first `a` and first `b` in `ul`. is it possible by css?

Comment: @ILoveCSS i cant add id as they are repeating themselves with ng-repeat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the **[`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)** pseudo-class and the [**adjacent sibling selector `+`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors).

```css
.a:first-child, /* Select the first child element */
.a + .b { /* Select the first element with 'b' class */
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="a"></li>
  <li class="a"></li>
  <li class="a"></li>
  <li class="b"></li>
  <li class="b"></li>
  <li class="b"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

try selector **:nth-child()** and **:first-child**

```
ul li:first-child {  
//some css 
}
```

and

```
ul li:nth-child(4) {
 //some css
}
```

Comment: What if first known position of class `b` is not known in advance?

Comment: i dont have exact position of both the li's

Answer (score 2):

You can't select with `class` as parameter for `first-child`. Instead use `~` operator to select the reverse. i.e apply styles for rest except first child.

```css
li.a, li.b{
 color: green; /*your styles for first elemenets*/
}
li.a ~ .a { /*differentiate rest of them from first*/
  color: black;
}
li.b ~ .b {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="a">1</li>
  <!-- I want to target this li -->
  <li class="a">2</li>
  <li class="a">3</li>
  <li class="b">4</li>
  <!-- and this li -->
  <li class="b">5</li>
  <li class="b">6</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can only target an element, a value of a named attribute in it, or the name of an attribute in the element. So, I would say the answer might be...no?  (limited to my own knowledge)

That being said..

Would it be possible to **insert** an empty `<li>` **before** each item you want to target?

If so, you can easily select those items like so:

```css
ul li {
  color: red
}
li:empty {
  display: none
}
li:empty + li {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li class="a">1</li>  <!-- I want to target this li -->
  <li class="a">2</li>
  <li class="a">3</li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="b">4</li>  <!-- I want to target this li -->
  <li class="b">5</li>
  <li class="b">6</li>
</ul>
```